# sout doesn't stike through the denominator

Tags: ulem

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}    

\usepackage{ulem} % strike through

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{\hat{N}} {O_{max} - O_{min}}
=
\frac{209.06 \hspace{1mm} \mu V} {(\sout{10777} - \sout{5268}) \hspace{1mm} \mu V}
\approx 3.8\%
\]

\end{document}
```

Here is what I got.

[image]

Comment: I don't think `ulem` commands are intended for use in formulae. Perhaps look at the [cancel package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cancel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\textup{\sout{<number>}}`. But you should also use `siunitx` instead of making (wrong) symbols by hand: units should always be upright. Also “max” and “min” should be upright.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ulem} % strike through
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textgreek} % to get a better “micro” symbol

\DeclareSIPrefix{\micro}{\text{\textmugreek}}{-6}

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{\hat{N}} {O_{\mathrm{max}} - O_{\mathrm{min}}}
=
\frac{\qty{209.06}{\micro\volt}}
     {\qty[parse-numbers=false]{(\textup{\sout{10777}} - \textup{\sout{5268}})}{\micro\volt}}
\approx 3.8\%
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe you want to make your command for striked out numbers:

```
\newcommand{\sonum}[1]{\textup{\sout{#1}}}
```

Comment: egreg is right, "min" and "max" should be upright, because these are not symbols for quantities, but words or abbreviated words. More about this for exemple in this this TUGboat article: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf, or in section 3 of the documentation of the *pm-isomath* package: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pm-isomath/pm-isomath.pdf.